# How can I expose a safe wrapper around an owned pointer?

Tags: rust

I'm wrapping a C library that has two structs: one has a pointer to the other.

```
struct StructA {
    void * some_mem;
};

struct StructB {
    void * some_mem;
    struct StructA * some_struct;
};
```

Both of these structs own memory, so my wrapper has constructors and destructors for both of them.

```
struct StructA(*mut c_void);

impl StructA {
    fn new() -> Self {
        StructA(c_constructor())
    }
}

impl Drop for StructA {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let StructA(ptr) = self;
        c_destructor(ptr);
    }
}
```

There's also a function that takes a pointer to `StructB` and returns its pointer to `StructA`:

```
const struct StructA * get_struct(const struct StructB * obj);
```

The user of this function should not free the returned pointer, since it will be freed when the user frees `obj`.

How can I wrap this function? The problem is that the destructor for `StructB` frees all its memory, including the one for `StructA`. So if my wrapping of `get_struct` returns an object, then the wrapped `StructA` will be freed twice (right?). It could instead return a reference to an object, but where would that object live?

I could have separate structs for `StructA` based on whether it's standalone and needs to be freed or if it's a reference, but I'm hoping that's unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I could have separate structs for StructA based on whether it's standalone and needs to be freed or if it's a reference, but I'm hoping that's unnecessary.

It's necessary.  The difference between an owned `StructA *` and a borrowed `StructA *` is precisely the same as the difference between a `Box<T>` and a `&T`.  They're both "just a pointer", but the semantics are completely different.

Something along these lines is probably what you want:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;
struct OwnedA(*mut c_void);
impl Drop for OwnedA {
    fn drop(&mut self) { }
}
impl OwnedA {
    fn deref(&self) -> RefA { RefA(self.0, PhantomData) }
}
struct RefA<'a>(*mut c_void, PhantomData<&'a u8>);

struct OwnedB(*mut c_void);

impl Drop for OwnedB {
    fn drop(&mut self) { }
}

impl OwnedB {
    fn get_a(&self) -> RefA { RefA(get_struct(self.0), PhantomData) }
}
```

In particular, it's worth noting that lifetime parameter on RefA lets the compiler make sure you don't use a `RefA` after the backing structure has been freed.

Answer (score 2):

> I could have separate structs for StructA based on whether it's standalone and needs to be freed or if it's a reference, but I'm hoping that's unnecessary.

I believe this would be the accepted pattern. For backup, I'd point to the fact that this is a normal pattern in the Rust library. `&str` and `String`, `&[T]` and `Vec<T>`, `Path` and `PathBuf`, and probably lots of others I can't think of.

The good news is that you can use similar patterns as these pairs, leveraging `Deref` or `DerefMut` to call down to shared implementation:

```
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

enum RawFoo {}

fn c_foo_new() -> *const RawFoo { std::ptr::null() }
fn c_foo_free(_f: *const RawFoo) {}
fn c_foo_count(_f: *const RawFoo) -> u8 { 42 }
fn c_foo_make_awesome(_f: *const RawFoo, _v: bool) { }

struct OwnedFoo(Foo);

impl OwnedFoo {
    fn new() -> OwnedFoo {
        OwnedFoo(Foo(c_foo_new()))
    }
}

impl Drop for OwnedFoo {
    fn drop(&mut self) { c_foo_free((self.0).0) }
}

impl Deref for OwnedFoo {
    type Target = Foo;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target { &self.0 }
}

impl DerefMut for OwnedFoo {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target { &mut self.0 }
}

struct Foo(*const RawFoo);

impl Foo {
    fn count(&self) -> u8 { c_foo_count(self.0) }
    fn make_awesome(&mut self, v: bool) { c_foo_make_awesome(self.0, v) }
}

fn main() {
    let mut f = OwnedFoo::new();
    println!("{}", f.count());
    f.make_awesome(true);
}
```

Then, when you get a borrowed pointer from your other object, just wrap it up in a `&Foo`:

```
use std::mem;

fn c_bar_foo_ref() -> *const RawFoo { std::ptr::null() }

// Ignoring boilerplate for wrapping the raw Bar pointer 
struct Bar;

impl Bar {
    fn new() -> Bar { Bar }

    fn foo(&self) -> &Foo {
        unsafe { mem::transmute(c_bar_foo_ref()) }
    }

    fn foo_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Foo {
        unsafe { mem::transmute(c_bar_foo_ref()) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut b = Bar::new();
    println!("{}", b.foo().count());
    b.foo_mut().make_awesome(true);

    // Doesn't work - lifetime constrained to Bar
    // let nope = Bar::new().foo();
}
```